# make android service running on backgroung even app is closed

Tags: android

I want to make two android services that kip running on background even when my app is closed or when all system reboots, but I have no idea about android. And that's what I did:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_ROOT_COMPLETED"/>

<service android:name="FirstService"></service>
<receiver android:name="FirstServiceReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.techrainner"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<service android:name="SecondService"></service>
<receiver android:name="SecondServiceReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.techrainner"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

this my MainActivity (WL : because I am using IBM MobileFirst)

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    WL.createInstance(this);

    WL.getInstance().showSplashScreen(this);

    WL.getInstance().initializeWebFramework(getApplicationContext(), this);

    Intent startFirstServiceIntent = new Intent(this,FirstService.class);
    Intent startSecondServiceIntent = new Intent(this,SecondService.class);
    startService(startFirstServiceIntent);
    startService(startSecondServiceIntent);

}
```

this is the first service :

```
class FirstService extends Service {

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
@Override
public  int onStartCommand(Intent intent,int flags,int startId){    
    return START_STICKY;    
}
```

}

the second service is the same as the first

the first receiver :

```
public class FirstServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    context.startService(new Intent(context,FirstService.class));

}

}
```

Also the second receiver is the same as the first.

Two services are running on background only when the app is opened, and they will be stopped when I close it.

Comment: Try this ,I'm sure this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61423600/android-service-type-floating-action-button-with-drag-and-drop-functionality

Answer (score 0):

As in Android documentation, it is written about Service as:

A service is "started" when an application component (such as an activity) starts it by calling startService(). Once started, a service can run in the background indefinitely, even if the component that started it is destroyed. Usually, a started service performs a single operation and does not return a result to the caller. For example, it might download or upload a file over the network. When the operation is done, the service should stop itself.

So when operation is done Service stops automatically. If you want to start your service even your app gets destroyed then you can use Alarm Manager Service. You can set a repeating alarm in your application to start your service in background.

And if your requirement is to sync your app with your app server and want to sync with server even your app is closed then you can use SyncAdapter Framework of Android.

Comment: I need this service to invoke MobileFirst http adapter that call a webservice in order to retrieve some data from database every hour and then this service will notify the user.